# can't install pyaudio with pip

Tags: python-3.7, pyaudio

```
ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SAADFA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-by_eac52\\pyaudio\\s
etup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --recor
d 'C:\Users\SAADFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lclkqelo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SAADFA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-by_eac52\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(t
okenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\SAADFA~1\App
Data\Local\Temp\pip-record-lclkqelo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\SAADFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-by_eac52\
pyaudio\
```

I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 but still get the error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.
```